# Traverse directory tree and display attributes

Tags: batch-file, windows-8

I have been trying to traverse a given directory tree on Windows 2008 (with a batch script) all the way down to the leaf and list the owner,last modified date and file size at each step. For eg,

```
C:\Folder1\Folder1a\File1.txt Adam 10/20/2017 1024 MB
C:\Folder1\Folder1a\File2.dat Peter 03/02/2018 2048 MB
C:\Folder1\Folder1b\File2a.dat John 06/21/2018 100 Bytes
C:\Folder2\Folder2a\Folder2aa\File2aa.zip Mary 15/08/2018 600 MB
```

So far i searched and could only dig up the follwing (which isn’t producing the desired output). I am from Unix background and only have very basic Batch knowledge. Can anyone please help ? Win Powershell ok too.

```
for /R %%f in (*) do dir /b /s /on /q “%%f”
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use bare format `/b` here as that is what you want to actually display, secondly you do not need to recurse through each file, then still do a dir on each, instead just do:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /q /on ^| findstr /vi "bytes"') do echo %%a
```

To redirect the output to file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /q /on ^| findstr /vi "bytes"') do echo %%a >> "D:\mypath\myfile.txt"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$list = @()
foreach ($f in (Get-ChildItem C:\YOUR\PATH\ -recurse))
  {if ($f.length -gt 1gb)
    {$list += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      Path = $f.FullName
      Owner = (Get-Acl $f.FullName).Owner
      'LastWrite' = $f.LastWriteTime
      'LastAccess' = $f.LastAccessTime
      'SizeMB' = "{0:N1}" -f ( $f.Length / 1mb )}
    }
  }
$list | sort path | export-csv -Path c:\your.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thank you.. works great.. how can i insert a delimiter between the properties/fields in the output $list and redirect to a file ?

Comment: $list | sort path | export-csv -Path c:\your.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation

Comment: one final help pls :- how to also get the Last Accessed Date and how to select the files which are mof size 1 GB or more ?